# Database choice for web site

Tags: database, social-networking

Is it possible to build a blog+forum+chat+image (a kind of social network) with using only one of the NOSQL DB? If yes, which is the best choice?

Answer (score 0):

Everything is possible, but I would recommend finding a framework that helps you and use whatever they use.

Answer (score 0):

Agreed with the answer nulvinge gave. I found that ASP with .NET is easily implementable. However if you want to pursue a free option or open source option you could use PHP, or Java-based. They are IMHO harder to implement.

They should all work with your NOSQL DB. You can create a DSN and access them via ODBC or JDBC.  I'm not sure if DB Connectors in .NET will allow connections directly so the ODBC/JDBC may be your only option to work with that DB format.

Answer (score 0):

If you use CouchDB, you can load it all with client-side JS. You won't have to worry about any kind of server-side logic.

Look at http://npmjs.org

It's the package manager for node, and when you search, everything is loaded from Couch at page load. Only static files are stored on the server, so the server logic is only:

1. Get request
2. Serve file

All of this is handled automatically by popular webservers like Apache and IIS.